# A linear but intractable PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a PDE of the following form, from a physics problem:
$$
y \left(\alpha \frac{\partial }{\partial y}+x \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x \partial y} \right)f(x,y) = \left( z_1 + z_2 x^\alpha y^{-2} \right) f(x,y)
$$

Function $f(x,y)$ is a real-space real-valued function and 
$z_{1,2},\alpha$ are real numbers, generally irrational.   The latter, specifically the $z_2$ coefficient term, seems to make all of the textbook methods (characteristics, Froebnius, Fourier transform) fail.   Does any one know weather a method exists to solve this?  Apologies if this is a simple question but, well, I am a theoretical physicist and it is not simple for me.

Comment: Saying this comes "from a physics problem" does not turn this into an on-topic question here - just asking about solving a certain PDE is off-topic here, but is probably on-topic at [math.SE].

Comment: I agree that this is not a physics question, but I would point out that the equation solvers in e.g. Mathematica are likely to cover all "solvable" cases. If that software can't reduce it to a known example of a solvable system, then you will have to go with approximation methods.

Comment: Is this homework? I can't understand! And I don't think it's that hard to try something with this equation. I can try, but first I want to know what is it for?

Comment: Thanks.  It is not "homework" of course.  It is a RG equation of parton distribution functions I am trying to solve analytically.   Every trick in, eg, Courant&Hilbert failed so far (though I now changed variables to logs of the respective variables and a Froebnius method might work) so I asked for suggestions.

Comment: How do you get a PDE from RG? I would've expected an ODE.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : a way to reduced form of PDE
$$
y \left(\alpha \frac{\partial }{\partial y}+x \frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x \partial y} \right)f(x,y) = \left( z_1 + z_2 x^\alpha y^{-2} \right) f(x,y)$$

$  \begin{cases}
    y=e^Y      \\
    x=e^{\frac{X}{\alpha}}  \\
    f(x,y)=g(X,Y) \\
  \end{cases}$
$\quad $
$  \begin{cases}
    dy=ydY      \\
    dx=\frac{1}{\alpha}xdX  
  \end{cases}$
$\quad $
$\alpha \frac{\partial g}{\partial Y}+\alpha \frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial X \partial Y}=\left( z_1+z_2e^{X-2Y}\right) g$

$  \begin{cases}
    z_1=\alpha c_1  \\
    z_2=\alpha c_2
  \end{cases}$
$\quad \quad\quad  $
$\frac{\partial g}{\partial Y}+\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial X \partial Y}=
\left( c_1+c_2e^{X-2Y}\right)g$

This is a kind of hyperbolic PDE on the form :
$$\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial X \partial Y}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial Y}+
F(X,Y)g(X,Y)=0$$
where $F(X,Y)=\left( c_1+c_2e^{X-2Y}\right)$

Hopping that could help...

Comment: You are right. I corrected the mistake. Of course, they were missing terms in the next equations. So I deleted them. Thanks for your remark

Comment: $f(x,y)$ and $f(X,Y)$ are different $f$'s also a sign of the latter is wrong. other than that - great job!

Comment: Bad notation corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on JJacquelin's answer and not guaranteeing that no mistakes
are made.

We have
\begin{equation*}
\partial _{Y}(1+\partial _{X})g+(c_{1}+c_{2}e^{X-2Y})g
\end{equation*}

If you put $u=X-2Y$ \ then
\begin{equation*}
\partial _{Y}(1+\partial _{u})g+(c_{1}+c_{2}e^{u})g=0
\end{equation*}
Now let $h=e^{u}g$ then
\begin{equation*}
(1+\partial _{u})e^{-u}h=e^{-u}\partial _{u}h
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\partial _{Y}\partial _{u}h=-(c_{1}+c_{2}e^{u})h
\end{equation*}
Next put $h=m(Y)n(u)$. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\partial _{Y}\ln m(Y)\partial _{u}\ln n(u) &=&-(c_{1}+c_{2}e^{u}) \\
\partial _{Y}\ln m(Y) &=&-\frac{(c_{1}+c_{2}e^{u})}{\partial _{u}\ln n(u)}=M
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
m(Y) &=&\exp [MY] \\
\partial _{u}\ln n(u) &=&-M^{-1}(c_{1}+c_{2}e^{u}) \\
n(u) &=&\exp [-M^{-1}(c_{1}u+c_{2}e^{u})]
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
g &=&e^{-u}\exp [MY]\exp [-M^{-1}(c_{1}u+c_{2}e^{u})] \\
u &=&X-2Y
\end{eqnarray*}
Edit: There were some mistakes. Below a new attempt.

With
\begin{equation*}
h(X,Y)=e^{X}g(X,Y)
\end{equation*}
we have
\begin{equation*}
\partial _{Y}\partial _{X}h(X,Y)=(c_{1}+c_{2}e^{X-2Y})h(X,Y)
\end{equation*}
New variables
\begin{equation*}
U=X-2Y,\;V=X+2Y
\end{equation*}

Then ($\left. {}\right\vert _{W}$ is the partial derivative with $W$
kept constant)
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left. \partial _{X}\right\vert _{Y} &=&\left. \partial _{U}\right\vert
_{V}+\left. \partial _{V}\right\vert _{U},\;\left. \partial _{Y}\right\vert
_{X}=-2\{\left. \partial _{U}\right\vert _{V}-\left. \partial
_{V}\right\vert _{U}\} \\
(\left. \partial _{X}\right\vert _{Y})\left. \partial _{Y}\right\vert _{X}
&=&2\{\left. \partial _{V}\right\vert _{U}^{2}-\left. \partial
_{U}\right\vert _{V}^{2}\}
\end{eqnarray*}

With
\begin{equation*}
h(X,Y)=k(U,V)
\end{equation*}
we then have
\begin{equation*}
2\{\left. \partial _{V}\right\vert _{U}^{2}-\left. \partial _{U}\right\vert
_{V}^{2}\}k(U,V)=(c_{1}+c_{2}e^{U})k(U,V)
\end{equation*}
Now try
\begin{equation*}
k(U,V)=m(U)n(V)
\end{equation*}
Then, omitting the subscripts on the derivatives,
\begin{eqnarray*}
m(U)\partial _{V}^{2}n(V)-\partial _{U}^{2}m(U)n(V) &=&\frac{1}{2}%
(c_{1}+c_{2}e^{U})m(U)n(V) \\
\frac{\partial _{V}^{2}n(V)}{n(V)}-\frac{\partial _{U}^{2}m(U)}{m(U)} &=&
\frac{1}{2}(c_{1}+c_{2}e^{U}) \\
\frac{\partial _{V}^{2}n(V)}{n(V)} &=&\frac{\partial _{U}^{2}m(U)}{m(U)}+
\frac{1}{2}(c_{1}+c_{2}e^{U})=M
\end{eqnarray*}
where $M$ is a separation constant. Hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
\partial _{V}^{2}n(V) &=&Mn(V) \\
\partial _{U}^{2}m(U) &=&\{M-\frac{1}{2}(c_{1}+c_{2}e^{U})\}m(U)
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I fail to follow this solution, can you clarify? Particularly why $\partial_u=\partial_X$. $M$ is expressed using  $n(u)$ which is expressed using $M$, so I'm not sure how to use it...just wanted to verify this solves the original problem...and failed:)

Comment: $∂{_u}=∂{_X}$ since both derivatives are taken at constant $Y$. As to $M$, on the left there is a function of $Y$ only and on the right of $u$ only, which is only possible if $M$ does not depend on each of them. Note that $M$ is a free parameter. For each $M$ the solution is in general different.

Comment: ok, $M$ is the constant of separation, not sure why is ok to fix $Y$, but the following mathematica code `D[E^(X - 2 Y) E^(M Y) E^(-(1/M) (a (X - 2 Y) + b E^(X - 2 Y))), Y] + 
   D[E^(X - 2 Y) E^(M Y) E^(-(1/M) (a (X - 2 Y) + b E^(X - 2 Y))), X, 
    Y] == (a (X - 2 Y) + b E^(X - 2 Y)) E^(X - 2 Y) E^(M Y)
    E^(-(1/M) (a (X - 2 Y) + b E^(X - 2 Y))) // FullSimplify` didn't show it was correct...

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky I am not familiar with mathematica, so I do not know what this code means. About $Y$ being constant, one can apply the chain rule. I checked with a different method and got the same result as before.

Comment: @Urgie : I don't agree with the second equation . It is better to have a different notation for $g(X,Y)$ and $g(u,Y)$. In case of ambiguity, let $g(X,Y)=G(u,Y)$ . Then $\partial_Y(1+\partial_X)g(X,Y) \neq \partial_Y(1+\partial_u)G(u,Y)$ : the result of derivation relatively to $Y$ is not the same for the first and second equation because $u$ is also function of $Y$.

Comment: @Urgje the code just substitute your solution into equation, but it could be that I still got something wrong.

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky There is something wrong with my calculations. I am working on it.

Comment: A new attempt was made. See the edit.